# When should a Python script be split into multiple files/modules?

Tags: python, coding-style, conventions

In Java, this question is easy (if a little tedious) - every class requires its own file. So the number of .java files in a project is the number of classes (not counting anonymous/nested classes).

In Python, though, I can define multiple classes in the same file, and I'm not quite sure how to find the point at which I split things up. It seems wrong to make a file for every class, but it also feels wrong just to leave everything in the same file by default. How do I know where to break a program up?

Comment: Nice question, I've been wondering about this too. I added a couple tags.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Remember that in Python, a file is a module that you will most likely import in order to use the classes contained therein. Also remember one of the basic principles of software development "[the unit of packaging is the unit of reuse](http://openlibrary.org/books/OL9297484M/Agile_Software_Development_Principles_Patterns_and_Practices)", which basically means:

If classes are most likely used together, or if using one class leads to using another, they belong in a common package.

Comment: What bugs me with that approach: Modules are getting really long with multiple classes in it. Isn't contraproductive to have files with thousands of lines? Think maintainablility etc.

Answer (score 4):

As I see it, this is really a question about reuse and abstraction. If you have a problem that you can solve in a very general way, so that the resulting code would be useful in many other programs, put it in its own module.

For example: a while ago I wrote a (bad) mpd client. I wanted to make configuration file and option parsing easy, so I created a class that combined ConfigParser and optparse functionality in a way I thought was sensible. It needed a couple of support classes, so I put them all together in a module. I never use the client, but I've reused the configuration module in other projects.

EDIT: Also, a more cynical answer just occurred to me: if you can only solve a problem in a really ugly way, hide the ugliness in a module. :)

Answer (score 2):

> In Java ... every class requires its own file.

On the flipside, sometimes a Java file, also, will include enums or subclasses or interfaces,  within the main class because they are "closely related."

> not counting anonymous/nested classes

Anonymous classes shouldn't be counted, but I think tasteful use of nested classes is a choice much like the one you're asking about Python.

(Occasionally a Java file will have two classes, not nested, which is allowed, but yuck don't do it.)

Answer (score 1):

Python actually gives you the choice to package your code in the way you see fit.

The analogy between Python and Java is that a file i.e., the .py file in Python is 
equivalent to a package in Java as in it can contain many related classes and functions.

For good examples, have a look in the Python built-in modules.
Just download the source and check them out, the rule of thumb I follow is 
when you have very tightly coupled classes or functions you keep them in a single file
else you break them up.